# Edit file with super-user rights

Tags: dired, files, sudo

When you have to edit system files, it's an usual situation that you launched Emacs with a normal user before, so the file will be write-protected. What can I do to gain root privileges? I mean something like `M-x sudo` from dired.

I don't want to launch Emacs as super-user and I don't want to quit it.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use `C-x C-f` and type out [`/su::/etc/hostname`](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#index-method-su) or [`/sudo::/etc/hostname`](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#index-method-sudo) as applicable.

This uses the [TRAMP](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Overview) package, which is distributed with Emacs. This package provides access to remote files, and more generally to files that Emacs can't open directly.

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of the `::` ?

Comment: The : is a separator; we supply it the second time to indicate that there are no more arguments. You can `/su:otheruser@localhost:`, for instance.

Comment: `/sudo::` is tramp shorthand for `sudo:root@<hostname>:`

Answer (score 14):

Use `find-file` with tramp. At the prompt `/sudo::/etc/ssh/ssh_config` will use sudo and a subshell to open that file with root privileges. When sudo is first used it will prompt for a password, but until that session closes you can edit any file with those permissions by prefixing with the existing `/sudo::` command.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/ for more details.

Answer (score 13):

There are today many packages that solve this problem (as of 2018). Some of them are:

- [`sudo-edit`](https://melpa.org/#/sudo-edit), allows to switch editing rights on an already opened read-only file. Just `M-x sudo` and type a password and you're done. After many years of use of this one, I think it is the more convenient for this need. `sudo-edit` allows you to open a file as any user, but it default on sudo if none provided.
- [`dired-toggle-sudo`](http://melpa.org/#/dired-toggle-sudo). It was [the first packaged solution](https://github.com/renard/dired-toggle-sudo/issues/1) I found after asking this question. It is Dired oriented, so if you prefer the *file* oriented version, see the first bullet of this list.
- Other solutions [exists on Melpa](https://melpa.org/#/?q=sudo)

Comment: `M-x sudo` works out of the box in doom emacs.

Comment: @michael-dorst I didn't know despite I am using it ^^

Comment: For Spacemacs users, `SPC f E` is the shortcut

Comment: In Doom Emacs, use `M-x` `doom/sudo-this-file` or `SPC f U` (M-x sudo didn't exist for me)

Comment: @walnut_salami Doom Emacs doesn't require an extra-package indeed. `M-x sudo` requires `sudo-edit`.

Comment: auto-sudoedit looks nice if you edit a lot of root protected files on your system, may try it out later, thank you

Answer (score 7):

If you use Helm. You don't need any external package / additional config. it works out of the box.

Inside `helm-find-files` you can invoke `find file as root` which bound to <kbd>C-c r</kbd>. This works for files or directories in `helm-find-files` session.

If you don't want to type password every time you open root files/dirs. Put the following line to your `~/.authinfo.gpg`

```
machine localhost port sudo login root password xxxxxx
machine your_machine_name port sudo login root password xxxxx
```

[source](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/168#issuecomment-11141879)

Answer (score 6):

If you use the `ivy` package, and have configured `counsel-find-file` to replace `find-file`, then one of the "ivy actions" pre-configured for you already is to edit the file as root. The default `hydra` keystroke for that action is `r`.