# How do I open a non-readable file from inside emacs when I opened emacs as a regular user?

Tags: sudo, root

The question pretty much says it all.  I opened emacs as a regular user and am trying to edit something in the /etc/ folder (I know this is dangerous etc. etc.)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95631/open-a-file-with-su-sudo-inside-emacs, for example `C-x C-f /sudo::/path/to/file`

Comment: True. I guess this question should be closed or linked to that answer directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is [packages](https://melpa.org/#/?q=sudo) that gives some utilities functions for this:

- `sudo-edit` for *opening buffers as root*
- `dired-toggle-sudo` for switching *from current user to sudo when browsind dired buffers*.

Also see the [Edit file with super-user rights](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52/edit-file-with-super-user-rights) question.