# Error when trying to save a file as root using Tramp and sudo

Tags: tramp, sudo, bytecode

I am following the directions laid out in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52/edit-file-with-super-user-rights) to edit my `sshd_config` file.

However when I try to save I get:

`byte-code: Wrong type argument: listp, 126`

Does anybody know why this would be and how I could fix it? (this prevents me from saving my file)

**EDIT**

Thanks to the comments I was able to narrow down the issue to the following lines in my init file:

```
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")  
(setq tramp-auto-save-directory auto-save-location)  
(setq tramp-backup-directory-alist auto-save-location)
```

Commenting them out fixed my issue

Comment: (1) Use `toggle-debug-on-error` to get a stack trace for the error. (2) Try editing and saving the file using a separate `emacs -Q` instance, which will indicate whether or not the problem was caused by your config.

Comment: Uh-oh. ``toggle-debug-on-error` does not print out anything different but trying (2) `emacs -Q` lets me save the file with no issues.  I take it this means it is a problem with my config? Any ideas how to start debugging that?

Comment: Yes. Recursively bisect your init file. Comment out 1/2 of it, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16,... You can use command `comment-region` to comment out selected text. With plain `C-u` it uncomments. Sounds slow but is fast (binary search).

Comment: After enabling debug-on-error, you tried to save the file again, yes? And it failed with the same error, but didn't produce a backtrace/debugger window?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what happened.  In messages I see debug-on-error enabled globally but I don't get a stack Trace and the error is the same.

Comment: Enable `tramp-debug-on-error`. It could result in better backtraces.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus it does not look like that is a real command.  However, I did try to enable `(setq debug-on-error t debug-on-signal t)` but I just got the same error message.

Commenting out my entire `init` file and re-reading it doesn't do anything, so there must be some variable that is being set on start and not working.

Comment: I meant `(setq tramp-debug-on-error t)`.