# Can I acquire root privilege to edit a system file without restarting emacs with `sudo`?

Tags: sudo

Sometimes, when I am running an emacs process (either  started with`emacs -nw` or `emacsclient -nw` with an emacs server daemon), I would like to edit a system file. Can I acquire root privilege without restarting emacs with `sudo`?

If I am using an emacs process started with `emacsclient -nw`, do I need to restart the emacs server process with `sudo`, i.e. `sudo emacs --daemon`?

Without restarting emacs server with `sudo`, is it possible to start emacs client with `sudo`? I can't find a solution:

```
$ ps aux | grep emacs
t         3235  0.0  0.3 398732 24904 ?        Ssl  Mar31   0:00 emacs --daemon

$ sudo emacsclient -nw /etc/profile
[sudo] password for t: 
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

    --socket-name
    --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
    --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

Comment: I have found that other post, I think it answers your question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52/edit-file-with-super-user-rights Executive resume: use `/sudo::filename` or `/su::filename`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11108)

Answer (score 4):

With a [Tramp](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) method:

```
C-x C-f /sudo::/your/system/file/here
```

That is just add the prefix "/sudo::" before your file and Emacs will ask you your sudo password. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Does `sudo` only apply to the system file specified in the same line, and not to the files to be opened in the future?

Comment: @Tim: Welcome, It works only for files with the "/sudo::" prefix.

Answer (score 2):

You should checkout [this page](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/core/autoload/files.el) of [DOOM](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/tree/develop). There is a function which does this:

```
(defun doom/sudo-find-file (file)
  "Open FILE as root."
  (interactive
   (list (read-file-name "Open as root: ")))
  (find-file (if (file-writable-p file)
                 file
               (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" file))))
```

I tested it on archlinux and it works. Before finding the file you are prompted for your root password. I haven't tested it on mac.